# VS code untangle and put in order entire code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to put in order some code in VS code, the software barely seems to indent properly.
I'm referring especially to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbc1j.png), what do I press to untangle and make it indented correctly?

I tried various shortcuts and auto-indentation and format on save is already enabled, am I missing something?

EDIT: I found the solution, I ran the code through a Markup Validator and there were some errors in the code that weren't highlighted. If you mess up VS Code just doesn't indent properly

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+I` to format the entire file --   `Ctrl+F` to just format the selected text.

Comment: they both do nothing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to check out an XML extension. Looks like two of the most popular (XML by Red Hat and XML Tools by Josh Johnson) should do the formatting you are looking for.

[image: XML by Red Hat and XML Tools by Josh Johnson]

The extension install page will give you more specific details on how you would go about formatting with these tools.

Some additional tips that might help you along the way to detangling XML.

1. Holding Alt + up or down arrow key will allow you to move line(s) up and down in the editor.
2. In the bottom bar you should see something that reads `Spaces: 3` or something similar. Clicking this will allow you to change that file's "tab" indentation level.